# How to animate a container on click in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am new to flutter animation, I have a stopwatch screen with a container that contains the stopwatch, a container with a list of laps, and 3 floating action buttons that do three things, reset, play-pause and lap. I want the stopwatch container to animate up when clicking on the lap button and then animate down when clicking on the reset button.

[image]
[image]

```
class _StopWatchScreenState extends State<StopWatchScreen>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {


final StopWatchTimer _stopWatchTimer = StopWatchTimer();
  final _isHours = true;
  late AnimationController controller;
  bool isPlaying = false;
  bool lapClicked = false;
  double value = 150.0;
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200));
  }

  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _stopWatchTimer.dispose();
    scrollController.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: value), // Issue here
                child: AnimatedContainer(
                  child: Center(
                      child: StreamBuilder<int>(
                          stream: _stopWatchTimer.rawTime,
                          initialData: _stopWatchTimer.rawTime.value,
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            final value = snapshot.data;
                            final displayTime = StopWatchTimer.getDisplayTime(
                                value!,
                                hours: _isHours);
                            return Text(
                              displayTime,
                              style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                  fontSize: 40.0, color: Colors.white),
                            );
                          })),
                  width: 350.0,
                  height: 450.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 5.0),
                      shape: BoxShape.circle),
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                  curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: lapClicked,
              child: Container(
                height: 280.0,
                child: StreamBuilder<List<StopWatchRecord>>(
                  stream: _stopWatchTimer.records,
                  initialData: _stopWatchTimer.records.value,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    final value = snapshot.data;
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return Container();
                    }
                    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
                      scrollController.animateTo(
                          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                          curve: Curves.easeOut);
                    });
                    return ListView.builder(
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: value.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final data = value[index];
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Lap ${index + 1}',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                        fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white70),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                                  child: Text('${data.displayTime}',
                                      style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                          fontSize: 30.0,
                                          color: Colors.white70)),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            const Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                              child: Opacity(
                                opacity: 0.1,
                                child: Divider(
                                  thickness: 1.5,
                                  color: Colors.white70,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                      controller: scrollController,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, bottom: 20.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    lapClicked = false;
                    value = 190.0;
                  });
                  controller.reverse();
                  _stopWatchTimer.onExecute.add(StopWatchExecute.reset);
                },
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.refresh,
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  toggleIcon();
                  if (isPlaying == true) {
                    _stopWatchTimer.onExecute.add(StopWatchExecute.start);
                  } else {
                    _stopWatchTimer.onExecute.add(StopWatchExecute.stop);
                  }
                },
                child: AnimatedIcon(
                  icon: AnimatedIcons.play_pause,
                  size: 35.0,
                  progress: controller,
                ),
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    lapClicked = true;
                    value = 10.0;
                  });
                  _stopWatchTimer.onExecute.add(StopWatchExecute.lap);
                },
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.timer,
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void toggleIcon() {
    setState(() {
      isPlaying = !isPlaying;
      isPlaying ? controller.forward() : controller.reverse();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Animated Container with visibility

see this for animated container

```
Visibility(
  visible:true,//controll to click on your lap button
  child: AnimatedContainer(),
)
```

[Animated Container](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-animatedcontainer-widget-ede30bd98931)

Comment: I tried using animatedContainer, and it works but the only problem is it doesn't animate and the container moves up suddenly, even after adding curves and changing the duration.

Answer (score 0):

I used `AnimatedContainer` to animate the stopwatch and fixed the animation issue by removing the `padding` property from the container and replacing it with a `margin` property